# Are there any observable Qt container classes?

Tags: c++, qt, observablecollection

I'm looking for general-purpose container/collection classes (e.g., lists, maps) that emit Qt signals when items are added or removed.

I know the standard Qt container classes don't do it. Anyone know of any OSS library that has observable containers?

I realize there are issues with templates and Qt features. If it were easy, I'd just do it myself instead of looking for an existing one. :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

But it is easy :) Just don't try subclassing the container class. Create a QObject subclass that contains an instance of the container you want to use and write Add and Remove methods that emit the signals you want when they are called.

Comment: Ok, that's true as far as it goes. I guess I wasn't specific enough. What I was really hoping for is a more "complete" solution that includes features like iterators, insertion into the middle, etc. I could write my own wrapper around another container class, but I'd rather not have to write wrappers around every method I wanted to expose. But if I don't find a better approach that's probably what I'll do.

Comment: As @Chris pointed out, this answer overlooks the lost benefits of Qt's container classes - iterators, foreach looping, etc.